# How do I access the properties of API in my react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am new to web development, and cant figure out how to access the properties of my API.
The API I am using provides with me the information of football teams. Given is the Schema and link of the API:
https://rapidapi.com/api-sports/api/api-football?endpoint=apiendpoint_bc5e37ef-299f-4656-98a3-ed0d9fa5b1d2
[image]

Given is my App.js code for the react application.

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      teamObj:{}
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/teams/team/33", 
          {"method": "GET","headers": 
            {"x-rapidapi-host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "a35b8572b7mshe694b9e8ac66df4p158c4bjsn4518b48e8965"}
          }
        )
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({teamObj : data}))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My fav team is: {this.state.teamObj.name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If you console.log(response) ,what do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            teamObj: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/teams/team/33', { method: 'GET', headers: { 'x-rapidapi-host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com', 'x-rapidapi-key': 'a35b8572b7mshe694b9e8ac66df4p158c4bjsn4518b48e8965' } })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => this.setState({ teamObj: data }));
    }

    render() {
        const data = this.state.teamObj;
        if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>;
        const teamData = data.api && data.api.teams && data.api.teams.length > 0 ? data.api.teams : [];

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>
                    My fav teams is:{' '}
                    {teamData.map((x) => {
                        return <div>{x.name}</div>;
                    })}
                </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an object, to access the teams array you need to use `data.api.teams` which is the array of the teams. To access the first team in the array use `data.api.teams[0]`

Change `teamObj` to teams.

```
state = {
  teams: []
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch("https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/teams/team/33", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "a35b8572b7mshe694b9e8ac66df4p158c4bjsn4518b48e8965"
    }
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({teams : data.api.teams })
    });
}
```

Render it like, team array will always contain one item, since you are passing the id of the team in your request. Access the team from the array with `this.state.teams[0].name`

```
<h1>My fav team is: { this.state.teams.length && this.state.teams[0].name }</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      teamObj:null
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/teams/team/33", 
          {"method": "GET","headers": 
            {"x-rapidapi-host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "a35b8572b7mshe694b9e8ac66df4p158c4bjsn4518b48e8965"}
          }
        )
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.setState({teamObj : data.api.teams})
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.teamObj)
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My fav team is: {
          this.state.teamObj && 
           this.state.teamObj[0].name 
          }</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```